# Converting numeric values to yyyymm dates in r

Tags: r, date

I am trying to covert the following date formats.  I have run into trouble using parse_date_time in lubridate package and the strfttime function since it either converts the entire column to the same date or because it keeps on returning the day value.  I don't want to see any dates in my solution.

```
 mydata=data.frame(dates=c(200102,200102,200111,200202),desired=c('2001-02','2001-02', '2001-11','2002-02'))
```

I want to return just the YYYY-mm format in my column.  I am having trouble doing this.  I have tried using

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
transform(mydata, desired = sub("(....)(..)", "\\1-\\2", dates))
```

This form is not that convenient for manipulation (plotting, etc.).  You might prefer to use the `"yearmon"` class from the zoo package which stores internally the year/months as year + fraction where fraction is 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  On output the default rendering is, for example, `Jan 2000`:

```
library(zoo)
transform(mydata, ym = as.yearmon(as.character(dates), "%Y%m"))
```